# Python typing for module type

Tags: python, type-hinting, python-typing

I am dynamically loading a Python module using `importlib.import_module` as follows

```
    def load_module(mod_name: str) -> ???:
        return importlib.import_module(mod_name)
```

Can somebody tell me what is the correct type annotation for a module type. The `typing` module does not contain one and I could not find an answer elsewhere.

Answer (score 103, accepted):

You're looking for [`types.ModuleType`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/types.html#types.ModuleType).

Comment: What would be best way to specify ModuleType to have some specific attribute?

Comment: @maciek I don't think that's possible. Type annotations are about validating, well, the *type* of a thing - not the thing's attributes. Though in the future it may be possible with the use of [`typing.Protocol`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0544/).