# What is the type hint for a (any) python module?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm, type-hinting, python-typing

I would like to add the (Python3) type hint for a module (class 'module'). The `typing` package doesn't provide one, and `types.ModuleType()` is a constructor that returns a module object for a specific name.

Example:

```
import types
def foo(module: types.ModuleType):
   pass
```

at least in PyCharm results in

> "Cannot find reference ModuleType in types.pyi".

Note that [Python typing for module type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48389157/python-typing-for-module-type) doesn't answer my question, as it does not explain that `ModuleType` is both a constructor as well as a type, as answered below.

Comment: It was [fixed](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-26025)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python typing for module type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48389157/python-typing-for-module-type)

Comment: @Gregory no, it doesn't.

Comment: @TheDiveO It does answer the question in the title, though. IMHO, the title should be updated to reflect the actual question. I've retracted the close vote.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

> and `types.ModuleType()` is a constructor.

That doesn't matter. [`types.ModuleType`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/types.html#types.ModuleType) is still a reference to a type, just like `str` and `int` are. There is no need for a *generic* `Module[typehint]` annotation, so `types.ModuleType` is exactly what you need to use here.

For example, the official [Python typeshed project](https://github.com/python/typeshed/) provides a [type hint annotation for `sys.modules`](https://github.com/python/typeshed/blob/25ac4d6af46104d0c7cb134ed09a61ca7092b62a/stdlib/3/sys.pyi#L43) as:

```
from types import FrameType, ModuleType, TracebackType

# ...

modules: Dict[str, ModuleType]
```

Don't be confused by the name here; `types.ModuleType` is a reference to the module type. It is not a separate factory function or something. The CamelCase name follows the convention of that module, and you use that reference because the type object is not otherwise available as a built-in. The `types` module [assigns the value of `type(sys)` to the name](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.7/Lib/types.py#L44).

If PyCharm is having issues with finding the `types.ModuleType` stubs, then that's either a problem with PyCharm itself (a bug), or the stubs currently bundled are outdated, or you used an incomplete typeshed set of stubs. See the PyCharm documentation on [how to use custom stubs](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/type-hinting-in-product.html#typeshed) to provide a fresh set.

If that doesn't work, it may be a bug in PyCharm dealing with the concept of *exporting* type hints. Typeshed currently [defines the `ModuleType` type hints in a separate module](https://github.com/python/typeshed/blob/95afb86022a51d6c74bb899f81668f793ea9e8da/stdlib/3/_importlib_modulespec.pyi#L17-L28), which are then [imported into the `types.pyi` stubfile](https://github.com/python/typeshed/blob/25ac4d6af46104d0c7cb134ed09a61ca7092b62a/stdlib/3/types.pyi#L12-L14) using the `from module import name as name` syntax. [PEP 484](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/#stub-files) states that imported type hints are not part of the stub *unless* you use the `as` syntax:

> Modules and variables imported into the stub are not considered exported from the stub unless the import uses the `import ... as ...` form or the equivalent `from ... import ... as ...` form.

It may be that PyCharm doesn't yet correctly handle such cases.

Comment: So this might be a PyCharm linting issue?

Comment: @TheDiveO: the error you show is either a PyCharm bug or an outdated local stub file, because I can see the [`ModuleType` type annotation](https://github.com/python/typeshed/blob/25ac4d6af46104d0c7cb134ed09a61ca7092b62a/stdlib/3/sys.pyi#L43), it is [exported from `types.pyi`](https://github.com/python/typeshed/blob/25ac4d6af46104d0c7cb134ed09a61ca7092b62a/stdlib/3/types.pyi#L12-L14).

Comment: It was an issue with PyCharm version and stubs; after switching to a snap-based most recent PyCharm installation, the warnings went away and PyCharm now correctly accepts `types.ModuleType`. Thank you very much for helping alot to clarify the situation: I didn't know about the typeshed infrastructure. Sad that there are so many troll downvotes when asking serious questions.

Comment: @TheDiveO: voting is rarely, if ever, 'trolling'. I note that you got upvotes after you added the information on PyCharm's reaction to using `typing.ModuleType`, making your question much more useful for other visitors to this site. The goal of Stack Overflow is to build a repository of questions that are useful to other with the same issue, and by adding more info you made it more useful. Voting is used here to indicate how useful others think a post is toward the goal. Also see [When is it justifiable to downvote a question?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/252677)