# How to type hint parameter of type <class 'module'>

Tags: python, types, module

I have a function that takes in a package and returns a list of classes in it (as well as subpackages) that inherits from `foo`.

```
def list_foo_classes_from_package(package) -> List[foo]:
    ...
    code to find attribute that is issubclass(attribute, foo) 
    ...
    return list_of_foo_classes

import boo
class_list = list_classes(boo)
```

I want to type hint the input package. however module is not a keyword. The closest thing I found was types.ModuleType, i.e.

```
def list_classes_from_package(self, package: types.ModuleType) -> List[foo]:
```

However I get a warning:

```
expected type ModuleType, got "__init__.py" instead
```

How do I type hint package as parameter to a function?

Comment: Show us code that actually produces the warning. Also, where is this warning coming from? mypy? An IDE?

Comment: `types.ModuleType` is the right type for a module. The problem lies elsewhere.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica, pycharm warning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turned out `types.ModuleType` was correct. It was an issue with Pycharm (thanks @user2357112 supports Monica). When searching for "Pycharm module type hint" on google led me to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53780795/4231985).