# How do I type "requests" when it's a function argument?

Tags: python, python-3.x, type-hinting

Python 3.9, mypi 0.910.

Suppose I have some code that lets you pass in something that can make http gets/posts, but falls back to the good old `requests` library if you don't. I might have done this for tests so I can easily pass in a stub.

```
import requests

def something(request_client = None):
  if not request_client:
    request_client = requests

  request_client.get('https://example.com')
  [...]
```

What is the appropriate type hint for `requests_client` there?

Comment: FYI, if you have an argument that defaults to None it is better to use `if request_client is  None` rather than `if not request_client`

Answer (score 0):

Either a union or if your custom class inherits from requests, you can just use that class itself.

If you wanted a [union](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Union)

```
request_client:Union[my_class,request]=None
```

or python 3.10

```
    request_client:my_class|request=None
```

Comment: I might be having a brain fart.  Is that like
```
from requests import request
[...]
def something(requests_client: request = None) 
```
?

Because mypy said `Function "requests.api.request" is not valid as a type` as well as `Module has no attribute "post"`.

if it's just the `import requests` requests, it says `Module "requests" is not valid as a type`

Comment: @JB - Specifically for modules at the minute, your only option for that is [ModuleType](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53780735/what-is-the-type-hint-for-a-any-python-module#:~:text=ModuleType%20is%20a%20reference%20to,(sys)%20to%20the%20name.)

Answer (score 0):

Your function as written doesn't take a function argument, it takes a module argument.  I'd suggest having it actually take a function argument, since that makes the typing *and* the testing/mocking easier:

```
import requests
from typing import Callable

Getter = Callable[[str], requests.models.Response]


def something(get: Getter = requests.get) -> None:
    get('https://example.com')
```