# correctly annotate the type <class 'function'> and <class 'module'> in python?

Tags: python-3.x

is there a way to annotate the parameter type of 'Function' and 'Module'? Just like dict is typing.Dict. But there is no such type as typing.Function or typing.Module. For example:

```python
# how do I annotate the type of 'handler_function' parameter?
def call_handler(handler_function: ?Function?):
    handler_function()

def handle():
    print("hello")

call_handler(handle)

# how do I annotate the type of 'mymodule' parameter?
def this_function_takes_module_arg(mymodule: ?Module?):
    # do something with the mymodule

import a_module
this_function_takes_module_arg(a_module)
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48389157/python-typing-for-module-type and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37835179/how-can-i-specify-the-function-type-in-my-type-hints

Comment: Thank you! I'm obviously not good at searching:)